# How can I set Windows Package Installer icon instead of default one in WiX

Tags: wix

In Wix by default It has been set with default installer icon, but I would like to set my company icon at this physical installer. How can I do this?

[image: Default Icon]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The icon you are asking about is managed by Windows Installer and can't be changed. It is a default icon assigned to all MSI packages by the OS. You can change the default icon for all MSI packages in the system registry, but this is most likely not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Previously I had been used InstaShield MSI Installer provided by Flextra. In this installer by default comes with a default image. I'm doing now conversion from Instalshield to Wix.

Comment: Was that output file actually an MSI? It could have been a bootstraper (exe), and that's totally different thing

Comment: Absolutely your are right, which was exe. I'm clarified now. Thanks yan.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko do you have any idea to set the bootstraper (.exe) icon?

Comment: @sky91, it looks like the `IconSourceFile` attribute of the `<Bundle>` element is what you need: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html

Comment: As a compliment to the icon being asked about there is the ability to set the installer's icon in Add/Remove Programs so they match: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/configure_arp_appearance.html

Comment: Unfortunately `IconSourceFile` only applies to `<Bundle>` but I only have `Product` tag. Any other way to set the icon?