# Changes the Icon's in Dialog's Wix Installer

Tags: xml, wix, installation, wix3.5, wix-extension

I have developed a setup for my project using WIX installer.I am really new to it.
Now i have completely finished developing the installer but i need to customize the Icon of the Dialog window.How to set the icon of our product to it.??

[image]

How to change this icon ??

I have tried the below code ,But  its not working?

```
<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="MySourceFiles\icon.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
```

Comment: Go to 'Add remove programs' - there you will find your icon

Comment: I need to change the Icon ,that is what i need .! @MortenFrederiksen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set Windows Package Installer icon instead of default one in WiX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295179/how-can-i-set-windows-package-installer-icon-instead-of-default-one-in-wix)

Answer (score 2):

The icon you are asking about is managed by Windows Installer and can't be changed. It is a default icon assigned to all MSI packages by the OS. You can change the default icon for all MSI packages in the system registry, but this is most likely not what you're trying to do.